# image segmentation the raccoon face into 5 grayscale segments

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, k-means

i am trying to segment the raccoon face into 5 grayscale segments , and i have done this , still , i am new

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cluster, datasets
from scipy import misc
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

face = sp.misc.face(gray = True)
n_clusters = 5
np.random.seed(0)
X = face.reshape((-1,1))
k_Means= cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters,n_init=4)
k_Means.fit(X)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3.5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(X, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

)

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What raccoon face? What are your input images, and what outputs do you have so far? We can't help you if we don't know what your exact problem is.

Comment: face = sp.misc.face  this is raccoon face . the output i have it doesnt show any graph just y-axis

Comment: Actually, it does not show the y-axis but the image. The problem is, that you have reshaped `X` to be of shape `(786432, 1)`, so what you see is one long chain of pixels.

Comment: so what should i do